# Static member Qt objects in C++

Tags: c++, qt, static

I have following class

```
class QBoardImages
{
public:
    QImage empty_white;
    QImage empty_black;
    QImage possible_move;
    QImage lighter;
    QImage choosed;
    QImage multiple_move;

    QImage blue_pawn;
    QImage blue_queen;
    QImage blue_skydiver;
    QImage red_pawn;
    QImage red_queen;
    QImage red_skydiver;

    QBoardImages();
};
```

with constructor, where I have:

```
QBoardImages::QBoardImages()
{
    QDir::setCurrent(QApplication::applicationDirPath());

    empty_white.load("images/board/white.png");
    empty_black.load("images/board/black.png");
    lighter.load("images/board/lighter.png");
    choosed.load("images/board/choosed.png");
    blue_pawn.load("images/board/blue_pawn.png");
    blue_skydiver.load("images/board/blue_skydiver.png");
    blue_queen.load("images/board/blue_queen");
    red_pawn.load("images/board/red_pawn.png");
    red_skydiver.load("images/board/red_skydiver.png");
    red_queen.load("images/board/red_queen.png");
    possible_move.load("images/board/possible_move.png");
}
```

and of course I want to load these images only once, but I am unable to do this.. What is the best way to load these images only once?

Thank you all

Comment: *"I want to load these images only once, but I am unable to do this.."* Why ? is it because you're making more than one instance of `QBoardImages` in your application? If so.. don't?

Comment: Yes it is. But I just need to use QBoardImages in multiple instaces of other class. Of course I could make only one instance of QBoardImages, but for this I would need static variable too... Certainly I could use some quick and ugly solution, but I want to find something elegant and universal. I am finding solution similar to static objects in Java for example.

Comment: 1) What's exactly wrong with using singletons? 2) You could also make those QImages *static* members of the class (i.e. global variables, in the class scope), but that's a bad idea for a number of reasons. This will lead you to use `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC` or pointers to QImages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest approach is:

1. Keep your class as it is now
2. Instantiate one object of this class at the beginning of the application
3. Provide a pointer or a reference to this object to any constructor of other classes that need these images.

This would look like this using references (use pointers if you prefer):

```
class MyOtherClass1 : // ...
{
public:
    MyOtherClass1(QBoardImages & boardImages) : 
        boardImages_(boardImages)
    {
        // ...
    }

private:
    QBoardImages & boardImages_;
};

class MyOtherClass2 : // ...
{
    // same pattern
}

int main(/* ... */)
{
    // ...

    QBoardImages boardImages;
    MyOtherClass1 object1(boardImages);
    MyOtherClass1 object2(boardImages);

    // ...
}
```

The alternative approach, less clean but may be easiest to implement since you do not have to pass the `boardImages` object to every constructor, is indeed to use static methods/objects. Singleton patterns are the typical way to implement this, but the issue in your case is that you call `QApplication::applicationDirPath()`, that might not be already accessible depending on where you use this class.

The way to deal with this is to instantiate and delete the memory yourself, and make sure you only use this class between these calls. For instance:

```
// QBoardImages.h

class QBoardImages
{
public:
    static QBoardImages * instance();
    static void makeInstance();
    static void deleteInstance();

    QImage empty_white;
    // ...

private:
    QBoardImages();
    static QBoardImages * instance_;
};

// QBoardImages.cpp

QBoardImages * QBoardImages::instance_ = 0;
void QBoardImages::makeInstance(){ instance_ = new QBoardImages; }
void QBoardImages::deleteInstance(){ delete instance_; }

QBoardImages * QBoardImages::instance()
{
    if(!instance_)
        makeInstance();

    return instance_;
}

QBoardImages::QBoardImages()
{
    QDir::setCurrent(QApplication::applicationDirPath());

    empty_white.load("images/board/white.png");
    // ...
}

// main.cpp

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QBoardImages::makeInstance(); // make sure to call this
                                  // after instantiation of app

    // ...

    int retValue = app.exec();
    QBoardImages::deleteInstance();
    return retValue;
}
```

Now, you can use your images anywhere between the calls `makeInstance` and `deleteInstance` using:

```
QBoardImages::instance()->empty_white
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is sad that THIS is cleanest solution.. but it works well.